# How can I fix missing IronPython project templates in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I installed IronPython yesterday.  After running Visual Studio the IronPython project template showed up but later it was gone.  I've tried repairing, uninstalling, and reinstalling without fixing the issue.  How can I make the templates show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the version of IronPython I had.

I renamed C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\IronStudio to IronStudio-old

I downloaded IronPython [2.7 Beta 1](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/48818)

I installed IronPython [2.7 Beta 1](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/48818) and the template worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with IronPython 2.7 RTM on VS 2010 SP1. I had the python tools for VS 1.0 installed before I installed IronPython. I did the following to resolve the issue

1. Uninstalled IronPython
2. Uninstalled Python tools for VS
3. Installed IronPython 2.7 RTM without the "Tools for VS" feature, this is provided by the python for VS installer
4. Installed Python Tools for VS