# Python template missing from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 64bit. I installed Python Tools during the installation process. When I first opened Visual Studio the template for Python was there.
But on restart it was gone.... I reinstalled Visual Studio and the problem happened again.
I installed it on another computer with Windows 7 64bit... And it has the same problem.
Python template just disappears on second launch of application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling Python Tools? Also what Python release are you using ? Check this also: [How can I fix missing IronPython project templates in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432606/how-can-i-fix-missing-ironpython-project-templates-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Yes, I tried reinstalling Python Tools. I also tried to install it separately using PTVS 2.2 VS 2015.msi. I'm using Python 3.5. I checked that thread and it didn't help. The only thing that helps is uninstalling Visual Studio and deleting all the files it left behind but the problem still persists and template disappears after second launch.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. :( Here are some screenshots to clarify the problem. This time installed with typical settings. Same problem.
http://imgur.com/a/h9Eah[1]

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstalled the python tools if it's already installed from the control panel
2. Download "Python Tools for VS 2015" from this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2
3. Install it
4. Restart VS, the Python template should appear without any problem.

Let me know if it worked for you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. :( Here are some screenshots to clarify the problem. This time installed with typical settings. Same problem.
http://imgur.com/a/h9Eah[1]